# Generate DWARF debug info in wasm binary from go?

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm trying to generate a wasm binary with DWARF debugging info via (non-Tiny) Go. Despite many iterations with the build, [gimli/dwarfdump](https://github.com/gimli-rs/gimli/blob/059c553fe73abba2b52b56983c32b7f33484629d/examples/dwarfdump.rs) keeps showing empty debug data sections (though it shows non-empty debug data when pointed at a native linux Go executable).
I don't know whether there's a tool bug or I'm just doing this wrong, would appreciate your comments.

Run the build this way:

```bash
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -a -work -x -gcflags="-N -dwarf=true -dwarflocationlists=false" -ldflags="-w=false" -o mmm . >build2.log 2>&1
```

(A lot of experimentation showed I had to specify these `-cflags` and `-ldflags` to override hardcoded defaults build was feeding the compile and link tools...)

Observe log file seems to invoke the tools with the right options:

```bash
--- snip ---
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -o $WORK/b001/_pkg_.a -trimpath "$WORK/b001=>" -p main -lang=go1.14 -complete -buildid wrV2MKYl_2wAOfC9V6TW/wrV2MKYl_2wAOfC9V6TW
 -dwarf=false -goversion go1.19.4 -N -dwarf=true -dwarflocationlists=false -nolocalimports -importcfg $WORK/b001/importcfg -pack ./0_components_vgen.go ./generate.go ./main_wasm.go
--- snip ---
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link -o $WORK/b001/exe/a.out -importcfg $WORK/b001/importcfg.link -buildmode=exe -buildid=NCMJg-CFGnRWYpYW5of2/wrV2MKYl_2wAOfC9V6TW/KT0X-n_LvOuN7jmi-7Tt/NCMJg-CFGnRWYpYW5of2 -extld=gcc -w=false $WORK/b001/_pkg_.a
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/buildid -w $WORK/b001/exe/a.out # internal
cp $WORK/b001/exe/a.out mmm
```

But dwarfdump (always) shows empty debug data sections:

```bash
$ dwarfdump mmm

.debug_info

.debug_types

.debug_pubnames

.debug_aranges

.debug_pubtypes
```